# Electron security (is my code is enough?)

Tags: security, electron, preload

I know about @reZach's answer about the electron security, and I know about his electron secured template.. I tried to use it, but it's just too much for today's me, I don't know anything about webpack, I know react not completely etc, the overall complexity of the template is too much for the current me. So I wanted to ask (maybe my code is good enough to be secured and safe?). I made a trading app, so I cannot give it to people not being sure that it is safe to use. I used just vanilla JS, express, localtunnel for receiving webhooks, and several modules. In short here's the code:

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const Store = require('electron-store');
const store = new Store();

const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
const axios = require('axios');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const localtunnel = require('localtunnel');

(async () => {
    const tunnel = await localtunnel({ port: 3000, subdomain: 'mysubdomain' });

    // the assigned public url for your tunnel
    // i.e. https://abcdefgjhij.localtunnel.me
    console.log(tunnel.url);

    tunnel.on('close', () => {
        // tunnels are closed
        console.log('connection closed');
    });
})();

const server = express();
const PORT = 3000;

let webhookMsg;
server.use(bodyParser.text());
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));

server.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Server is ready!');
});
server.post('/', (req, res) => {
    webhookMsg = req.body;
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

let win;

async function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 500,
        height: 550,
        titleBarStyle: 'hidden',

        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false, // is default value after Electron v5
            contextIsolation: true, // protect against prototype pollution
            enableRemoteModule: false, // turn off remote
            preload: path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'preload.js'), // use a preload script
            backgroundThrottling: false,
        },
    });

    // Load app
    win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'));
    win.setAlwaysOnTop(true, 'screen');
    // win.removeMenu();
    // rest of code..
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

// NEXT IS MY APP MAIN LOGICS ON RECEIVING MESSAGES AND SENDING API REQUEST TO AN EXCHANGE PLATFORM AND GIVING BACK THE ANSWERS TO THE 'front-end script js file'
//for example
ipcMain.on('loadPrefs', () => {
const allPrefs = store.get('prefs');

win.webContents.send('prefs', allPrefs);
});

ipcMain.on('giveBalance', async e => {
const [apiKey, secret] = fs.readFileSync('api.txt').toString('UTF8').replace(/\r/g, '').split('\n');
const timestamp = Date.now().toString();

const params = {
    api_key: apiKey,
    timestamp: timestamp,
};
let orderedParams = '';
Object.keys(params)
    .sort()
    .forEach(function (key) {
        orderedParams += key + '=' + params[key] + '&';
    });
orderedParams = orderedParams.substring(0, orderedParams.length - 1);

var hmac = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA256, secret);
hmac.update(orderedParams);
const sign = hmac.finalize().toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);

try {
    const res = await axios.get(`https://api.bybit.com/v2/private/wallet/balance?&api_key=${apiKey}&sign=${sign}&timestamp=${timestamp}`);
    // console.log(res.data);
    const responseObj = res.data.result.USDT.equity;
    win.webContents.send('balance', { responseObj });
} catch (error) {
    // console.log(error);
}
});
```

**preload.js**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

// Expose protected methods that allow the renderer process to use
// the ipcRenderer without exposing the entire object
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', {
    send: (channel, data) => {
        ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners(channel);

        let validChannels = [
            // myChannelsList
        ];
        if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
            ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
        }
    },
    receive: (channel, func) => {
        ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners(channel);

        let validChannels = [
            // myResponseChannelsList
        ];
        if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
            // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`
            ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
        }
    },
});
```

In short, I just copied this reZach's example from this answer and added my JS logics to it.
Could you please tell is it secured and safe to use, I just worry that somebody can get the user's api keys for example and take their money away:) Thank you

Comment: sorry, ok, reading this guide now:) https://www.debugandrelease.com/the-ultimate-electron-guide/

Comment: is it safe to store data outside of ipcMain.on('message', ()=>{}) functons in the main script?

Comment: added a sandbox: true to webPreferences, thank you:)